# Python 3.x IndexError while using nested For loops

Tags: arrays, for-loop, numpy, python-3.x, 2d

So I've been trying to code a tabletop game that I made a long time ago - I'm working on the graphic section now, and I'm trying to draw the 9x7 tile map using nested For loops:

I'm using the numpy library for my 2d array

```
gameboard = array( [[8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8],
                [8, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 3, 8],
                [0, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0],
                [0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0],
                [8, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 8],
                [8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8]] )
def mapdraw():
for x in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
    for y in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
        if gameboard[(x, y)] == 1:
            #insert tile 1 at location
        elif gameboard[(x, y)] == 2:
            #insert tile 2 at location
        elif gameboard[(x, y)] == 3:
            #insert tile 3 at location
                    #this continues for all 8 tiles
                    #graphics update
```

When I run this program, i get an error on the line "if gameboard[(x,y)] == 1:"
"IndexError: index (7) out of range (0<=index<7) in dimension 0"

I've looked for hours to find what this error even means, and have tried many different ways to fix it:  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: `IndexError` means you tried to index with some value outside the array bounds (for example, indexing at `[10, 10]` in an 8x8 grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to index the array using `[y,x]` because the first coordinate is the row index (which, for you, is the `y` index).

As an aside, *please* iterate over a `range` instead of an explicit list!

```
for x in range(9):
    for y in range(7):
        if gameboard[y, x] == 1:
            #insert tile 1 at location
        ...
```

Comment: Ah, thanks very much!  I had it set as a range function earlier, but took that out when I thought it was the cause of the error.  It all works as expected now!